# What kind of hyphen/dash should I use instead of bullets in itemize lists?

Tags: lists, punctuation, itemize

Bullets are cute, but I don't really like them for my `\itemize` lists (in Comp Sci papers, written in English). I want something more, shall we say, drab, humdrum, pizzazz-less... :-)

Anyway, I was thinking hyphens, or dashes. But what kind? Which are "normally" used for lists? Or maybe I should ask - which "look better" in type?

Bonus points for suggestions regarding what to do with nested `\itemize`'s.

Comment: Items on the second level already have dashes (in most classes anyway). `article` uses this: `\newcommand\labelitemii{\normalfont\bfseries \textendash}`. If that is “normal” use? No idea… about looking better or worse: trust your eyes :)

Comment: For example, smfart/smfbook classes have this definition: `\def\labelitemi{\bfseries --}% \upshape already done by \itemize`, 
`\def\labelitemii{$\m@th\bullet$}
\def\labelitemiii{$\m@th\ast$}
\def\labelitemiv{$\m@th\cdot$}`

Comment: So, I am throwing in the simple `--` into the mix of things for you to experiment with. :-)

Comment: What your readers will recognize and appreciate depends to some extent on the linguistic setting: English, French…  And some bullets are nicer than others (my favorite is the one in GoudySaks).

Comment: @Thérèse What's this GoudySaks?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina https://www.fontshop.com/families/goudy-saks

Comment: @Thérèse Thanks. Now I understand your comment :)